# How to install React js with Spring framework?

Tags: spring, reactjs

I can't figure out how to install React.js for Spring framework.

A website said to first install NPM. Yes, I did that.

But how can I use React.js in Spring MVC?

1. mac and windows need to install NPM?
2. just use use CDN -> this case occur error
3. how to searching basic course
4. only use spring boot?
5. could you give a Web site address for how to install Spring
   Frameworks with React.js
6. could you give to me tips for how to install React.js for Spring
   Frameworks?

I'm a beginning developer.

Comment: What is Real js? Do you mean ReactJs or RevealJs by that?

Comment: I changed wrong word. it is not Real js just React js.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I can give you is to walk through this tutorial, step by step.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/01/react-js-and-spring-data-rest-part-1-basic-features

To answer your first question, no, you do not need to use node.js tools to use React with Spring MVC.  The tutorial above says:

> This tutorial won’t go into extensive detail on how it uses require.js
>   to load JavaScript modules. But thanks to the frontend-maven-plugin,
>   you don’t have to install any of the node.js tools to build and run
>   the code.

Comment: Thanks. I already download spring source file. But i can't run that source.
i just import my eclipse that source file. that source isn't running.
I was download eclipse plugin by spring 3.7 in eclipse market.

Comment: I had also problem with Eclipse, my problem was that during downloading maven packages the Eclipse failed. Try to run ```maven clean package``` in command line. If it is the same problem you will see ```[WARNING] error reading /Users/cervenkb/.m2/repository/<SOMEMODULE> (bad signature)```. Fix this and run ```mvn clean pacakge``` again. After success you can try it with ```mvn spring-boot:run```. This is how you ensures that the problem is not in code but in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

`Spring MVC` and `ReactJS` follow some different concepts of designing your webapplication. With Spring MVC your create most of the time server side rendered webapps with `JSP`s or you use a template engine like `Thymeleaf`.

With `ReactJS` you are building a Singe Page Application (SPA) which can be accessed with a **SINGLE** HTML file, often `index.html` and your JavaScript is doing the rendering. With `Spring MVC` you provide several `.html` files and use Spring to route the different routes to your different `.html` files and render them on the server side.

The only thing I can guess is to serve your finally built `ReactJS` which consists only of one `.html` and several `.js` and other assets with a Spring MVC application which acts like a simple Webserver.

Furthermore you can use Spring MVC to provide RESTful interfaces for your React application.